# IIS - local host works but Application url do not work

Tags: windows, iis, server, windows-server-2016

I have installed an application on IIS. The localhost is displayed without any problem, however i am unable to access the application. http:\localhost\application.

I am having the following error message :

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2021-04-07 07:16:30

#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2021-04-07 07:16:30 ::1 GET /AnalyticsApplication - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 302 0 0 2849
2021-04-07 07:16:30 ::1 GET /AnalyticsApplication/Error/Index aspxerrorpath=/AnalyticsApplication 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 302 0 0 68
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: What is your application? How did you deploy the project to IIS?